# Recuperar array de laravel en Created() en vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una petición por medio de GET hacía Laravel para obtener información de una nota de venta (esto para que pueda ser redireccionado desde otro portal) https://misitio.com/obtenerInformacion?idNota=1

Al momento de hacer la consulta en Laravel, quiero regresar dicha información junto con la vista

```
public function obtenerInformacion(Request $request){

     return view('vista')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Quiero recuperar el arreglo 'data' en el Created() en Vue, o en su caso puede que este mal que lo quiera recuperar ahí

Answer (score 0):

creo que esta haciendo mal las cosa, si utiliza vue y laravel lo tiene que retorman como un json, lo que esta haciendo es retorna a una vista

1. método para retorna un dato a una vista larave

   ```
   <?php

            public function obtenerInformacion(Request $request){
         $datas=[];
             return view('vista', [
                  'datas' => $datas,
                ]);}
        ?>
   ```

este método me retorna los datos dentro de la **vista.blade.php** por el cual con vue no es posible obtener los datos

2. método de obtener los datos por JSON y vue

en el archivo **web.php**  añader una url, son datos relativos por el cual la url del navegador es:  *obtenerInformacion

```
  Route::get("obtenerInformacion", "MiInformacionController@obtenerInformacion");
```

y en el controlador

```
 public function obtenerInformacion(Request $request){
                $id = $request->get("idNota");
                $data = CharlasSSTModel::findOrFail($id);                    
                return response()->json($data);

              }
```

en su archivo de vue

```
methods: {

    obtenerInformacion() {
                axios.get(`obtenerInformacion?idNota=${this.input_id}`).then(response => {
                    this.data_foraneo= response.data;
                });
            }
}
```